# Swift doing async automatically

Tags: swift

```
func detect(image: CIImage) {
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model) else {
            fatalError("Loading CoreML Model failed.")
        }

        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else {
                fatalError("Model failed to process image")
            }
            print(results)
        }
        print("First")

        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

        do {
            print("Second")
            try handler.perform([request])
            print("Third")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

In this example, what gets printed in console is:

First,
Second,
"Results",
Third

So my question is,
why does this code work even though handler.perform function is not inside the request completion handler?

This seems different to NodeJS where the data in "request" variable is not ready when it reaches handler.perform.

Comment: what was your expectation ?

Comment: @amigo: Why should this not work?  request is a closure that you pass to `handler.perform([request])` and `.perform` stores this closure and executes it asynchronously what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`perform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880297-perform) will:

> The function returns after all requests have either completed or failed.

Since the requests are completed *before* it returns, it is synchronous. The completion handler you passed to `VNCoreMLRequest` will be called before `perform` returns. Its return value also indicates whether all the requests have succeeded. If it returns before all the requests have completed, how does it know whether all of them have succeeed? :D

Because of `perform`'s synchronous nature, you should run it on another dispatch queue, so as to not block the main queue, like Apple did in all their sample code ([1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_objects_in_still_images), [2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml)):

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    do {
        try imageRequestHandler.perform(requests)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to perform image request: \(error)")
        self.presentAlert("Image Request Failed", error: error)
        return
    }
}
```

Remember to switch back to the main queue when you are in the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is nothing async here. According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimagerequesthandler/2880297-perform

> Returns true if all requests were scheduled and performed. If the return value is false, check the error parameter.

Hence, if the function returns, all requests have been scheduled and performed.